# Facebook Sharer Parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I'm trying to share a page that is behind a login page but obviously this causes problems for facebook sharer and the open graph tags... So my question is, how can I share facebook links that cannot be crawled by the og tags? I can use the twitter share using parameters which suits my needs but I've heard facebook has stopped supporting this method.

Basically the page I share has an id as a query string which is used to query the database and then grants access to a particular profile.

Hope this makes sense... if anything is unclear let me know.

Cheers

Comment: First of all, you should think about whether sharing of login-protected pages makes that much sense in the first place. Depending an where users share and who with, a lot of people that are not users of your site already might see those links – likely to only get a “you are not logged in” message when they follow them, and that is not a very good user experience …

Comment: The Feed dialog still allows to specify parameters such as title, description and thumbnail at run-time – but be aware, this doesn’t always work, I have read a lot of questions lately by people reporting that this doesn’t work on mobile. Your other option is to add an exception to your login system, so that the FB scraper gets access to everything (it can be recognized by its User-Agent).

Comment: Sorry CBroe, I have a solution... I have the og tags in place and instead of sharing the current page I'm going to share the public facing url which has a encrypted id associated, so those who have the page shared get access.